# What is a "transparent" adverb?

Tags: meaning

A scholar writes: A transparent adverb can only be used after sentence negation or after another sentence adverb if it carries a stress:

> Conrad has not really left.
>   Conrad has probably really left.

I do not understand why "really" in those sentences is called a "transparent" adverb.

Comment: If "really" can only be used after "not" or another adverb, then a sentence like "Conrad has really left" would be incorrect. I don't think it is.

Comment: Could you provide more context for this scholar's statement?--a link to the passage would be just dandy.

Comment: I have located the book: http://books.google.com/books?isbn=354017236X

Comment: @MετάEd: Could you fold that into the question?

Comment: @Noah Unfortunately Google Books does not provide enough of the passage to be useful in the question.

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CEYQFjAG&url=http://www.broccias.net/research/paper_Broccias%2520%28with%2520Abstract%29.pdf&ei=zmFvUOPVBoa0igL74oCQCQ&usg=AFQjCNF4fXOoEBq15s6Ix4lWxA6Dqr63gQ&sig2=z8dmo_jxRxn9xGEln77cJw&cad=rja) by Cristiano Broccias contains a couple of clearer explanations of transparent adverbs:

> 1. Sally *angrily* shouted at them.
> 2. Sally *angrily* read the letter.
>
> *Angrily* in (1) can be paraphrased as "out of anger." It stands for the **motive** which drove Sally to shout. *Angrily* in (2), by
>   contrast, refers to the **consequence** of Sally's reading the letter:
>   reading the letter made Sally angry. Geuder (2000) and Himmelmann and
>   Schulze-Berndt (2005) call such uses *transparent*.

Broccias gives a further example to illustrate that a transparent adverb is used to convey a **consequence**.

However, I'm not sure how to apply this criterion to the example that the OP cites:

> 1. Conrad has not really left.
> 2. Conrad has probably really left.

*Really* can be paraphrased as "in actual fact" or "in reality." However, it's difficult to see how it's either a motive or a consequence in either sentence.

Either Monika Doherty is not using *transparent adverb* in the same sense as either Broccias or [Geuder](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CF8QFjAJ&url=http://d-nb.info/964908301/34&ei=zmFvUOPVBoa0igL74oCQCQ&usg=AFQjCNHz8ukVEkYoDIrtL5caZSgiWoTJgw&sig2=qcmCMRZD7yz8Vz73WeCLaw&cad=rja), or her example isn't well-chosen.

Comment: Many thanks to everyone who answered, and especial thanks to those who took the effort to do some online research.